# Pyspark : collect all the keys in a given data frame column

Tags: pyspark

I'm a spark beginner. I'm trying to collect all the keys present a particular column, with different rows having different key value pairs.

```
|-- A: map (nullable = true)
|    |-- key: string
|    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)


   A                                     ID
name: 'Peter', age:'25'.                  5
name: 'John', country:'USA', pet:'dog'    7
```

I need to transform this to a data frame with all the keys as new columns. I tried exploding the column, which will create new "key" and "value" columns but the data frames is a few GB big, and the spark job fails.

```
dataframe.select(explode("A")).select("key").show()
```

The expected result is :

```
   name    age   ID  country  pet
   Peter   25    5    null    null
   John    null  7    USA     dog
```

Comment: Create some example code which shows Your problem, [how to write question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions, I've edited the question.